# Is there any way to aggregate and/or concatenate the values of a column as comma separated items in a Group By query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by, concatenation, aggregate-functions

Here's the data which I retrieve using a multilayer `SELECT` query:

```
TID StartID EndID   StartTime               EndTime                 ResName
1   1491005 1491020 2013-07-15 06:43:50.000 2013-07-15 06:44:38.000 NULL
1   1501403 1502819 2013-07-15 12:52:41.000 2013-07-15 13:40:10.000 TT Bill
1   1490838 1508632 2013-07-15 06:35:25.000 2013-07-15 16:57:10.000 TA Brady-MGR
1   1491039 1491267 2013-07-15 06:45:32.000 2013-07-15 06:56:35.000 TA Larry-Drv
2   1508739 1508939 2013-07-15 07:33:32.000 2013-07-15 07:44:35.000 TN John
```

I need to `GROUP` this data by **TID** So that all **ResName** values having same **TID** are displayed as Comma Separated Values.

**For Example:** For **TID** 1, value of the last column **TIDNames** must be **TT Bill,TA Brady, TA Larry**.

I am using following query for **GROUPING**

```
    Select G.TID,
    Min(G.StartId) As MinSID, Max(G.EndId) As MaxSID, 
    Min(G.StartTime) As MinStartTime, Max(G.EndTime) As MaxStartTime,
    'I need comma separated ResName values for my TID here' As TIDNames
    From ( 
           nested select - this is where I get the above data which needs further grouping
    ) G
    Group By G.TID;
```

I have tried to simulate this scenario in this fiddle (instead of nested select I have stored the data in a table): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3267/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FOR XML PATH to concatenate the values into a single row:

```
Select t1.TID,
  Min(t1.StartId) As MinSID, 
  Max(t1.EndId) As MaxSID, 
  Min(t1.StartTime) As MinStartTime, 
  Max(t1.EndTime) As MaxStartTime,
  STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t2.ResName
          FROM Item t2
          where t1.TID = t2.TID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS TIDNames
From Item t1
Group By t1.TID;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3267/4).

If the data you are querying is from another query, then you can use a CTE:

```
;with cte as
(
  select * from yourqueryHere
) 
select t1.TID,
  Min(t1.StartId) As MinSID, 
  Max(t1.EndId) As MaxSID, 
  Min(t1.StartTime) As MinStartTime, 
  Max(t1.EndTime) As MaxStartTime,
  STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t2.ResName
          FROM cte t2
          where t1.TID = t2.TID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS TIDNames
From cte t1
Group By t1.TID;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3267/7)

Comment: Item table is just a simulation of sub select. Any way to deal with that? I do not have this data stored in actual table.

Comment: I guess I can use CTE. Let me try.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks for your help and time. +1 and Correct solution.

Comment: @Learner Yes, that was a typo.